# Vue3 is there a way for an external methods call a composition method?

Tags: vuejs3

I have an external js file imported into a script setup. Is it possible for the external script call an internal function?

This is my code:

**app.js**

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

**validation.js**

```
export const validate = (form, check=false)  => {
  // validation rules
  if (check) update(form);
}
```

**component.vue**

```
 <script setup>
import validation from '@/validation.js';
import { useForm  } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

const update = (key, value, empty=false) =>
{
  form.post(route('update'), 
  {
        onSuccess: (data) => {
          console.log(data);
        },
        onError: (data) => {},
  });
}
</script>
```

When I call validate return the following error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: update is not defined**

Thanks

Robert

Comment: `validation.js` is its own module with its own scope so needs to be told what the `update` function is.

Comment: Just for information I solved my issue using another small function that in the composition call the validation and if the validation return true call the update, simply.